# Can a user define an automatic macro variable?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have two different SAS platforms and I run a macro on each platform to create a report.

I use

`%include "&MACRO_Path.";`

what do i want is creating an automatic variable "MACRO_PATH" which contains file location. So when I start my SAS session, I  do not need to define the file location in that MACRO_PATH variable.

I know one way is I can create auto executable file in the location which contains the code line but just wondering if I can create automatic Macro variable.
I, also, know automatic macro variables are the ones which are created by macro processor.

But is there any work around?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "automatic macro variable" - you seem to know about the autoexec options. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How are you running SAS?  Is this DM SAS ("desktop" SAS) or through Enterprise Guide or SAS Studio or a text editor or, something else?

Comment: @Joe I am using SAS Enterprise Guide.

Comment: @Therkel Automatic Macro Variable which are created  by SAS like SYSDATE, SYSTIME etc. Autoexec file, it means this file will execute automatically when I start my SAS session.

Answer (score 4):

If you just have two hosts and you know which ones they are then you might be able to use SYSSCP or SYSHOSTNAME.  For example if one is a Windows host and another a unix host you might do this.

```
%let macro_path=%sysfunc(ifc(&sysscp=WIN,c:\mymacros,~/mymacros));
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  I also think the appropriate place to put that would be in an autoexec.sas file.  That way if the HOST name changes you don't need to update 500 different SAS files that all contain that line of code.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know the ifc function

Comment: I think this is a suggestion that may well work for many SAS programmers, but is too much of a kludge for good modern development practices.  A little more work is better than hiding hardcoded paths, particularly in an autoexec.sas program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Enterprise Guide, you can do this at the *project* level by using the Autoexec process flow.  Name one process flow "Autoexec" and select the option that automatically runs that process flow when you open the project.

What I typically do for projects where I have, say, Dev, Test, and Prod environments, is to have linked files that are not synced in version control, stored in the project directory (you need to enable Relative File Paths in the Project Properties under File References).  That contains the value for the macro variable(s) that are specific to the environment.

Then, that shortcut is stored in the autoexec process flow.  The project itself is in version control, so when I sync my dev changes with test or prod it has the correct local references.